# Where did Gilligan's Island get the sound for the Mars probe in S02E04?

Tags: sound-effects, gilligans-island

While watching Gilligan's Island 2x04 "Smile, You're on Mars Camera", I was amused to note that the probe makes the same sound as Spock's scanner/viewer on the *Enterprise* bridge does in *Star Trek* (TOS). At first I thought it was a *Trek* reference on the part of *Gilligan's* producers, until I realized that it was a year too early for that reference to be made.

Was this simply a stock sound effect used for "high-tech" stuff on TV at the time?